# Can i host ASP.NET on an apache server?

Tags: asp.net, apache, webserver

I have heard of the pains of setting up IIS.   On a windows box, can I simply drop a ASP.NET application into Apache server and have it work? Or are there any other server alternatives?  I am relatively new to web server concepts.  I have heard suggestions for the server in mono but it doesn't seem practical using mono on a windows box, I could use a Linux box with mono, which wouldn't surprise me if it worked better then a windows solution, but for arguments sake this question is directed towards a windows box.

Thanks

Comment: @Simon has the answer below, but for the record, getting IIS to work well is not harder than getting apache to work well.  My experience is the reverse.  IIS 7+ on Windows 2008+ is optimized for ASP.NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [mod_aspdotnet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-aspdotnet/).

> mod_aspdotnet is a loadable Apache 2 module for serving ASP.NET content using the Microsoft's ASP.NET hosting and .NET runtime within the Apache HTTP Server process.

Comment: Is this technology outdated for .Net3.5?  It seems like it stopped development prior to 2.0?  Or is there other documentation not than on the sourceforge site.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there's a [mod_mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono) you can use.

Answer (score 2):

If you are windows user then you can go along with [mod_aspdotnet](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-aspdotnet/)

and if you are linux user then you can use mod_mono.